# Java Bot get values from window/screen

Tags: java, image, int, bots

ok this is my first time ever posting. Sorry if i am not specific enough.

i am trying to make a bot using java coding, using eclipse. the game i am playing(dark summoner) does not have status bars but, fractions such as 23/47 energy 240/300 battle points.  i can't find a way to get the values from the top or the screen into my code. also to make this easier i thought i could get my code to focus on the window opened with the game in it, and can not find a way to do that.

the idea behind the bot so far is to have it attack when i reach enough battle points. when this is achieved i plan on making it usable on any or most energy based games like mafia wars age of baymont millions to list

---

so in short my question is how do i get values from a specific area of an image, to my code using java

---

oh yeah i am a noob

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the number from the image, but you can assign number to the image. After displaying proper image, you will know what number is connected with it. Divide whole number into digits and display each digit alone, composing the whole number.

If the only aim of the application is to get text from a image, you can think about image processing and some algorithms, but it time consuming.

Comment: what if it were text not an image??

Comment: You mean: get text to you application from a text shown on display not from a image? If you have status bar and points, then you should have somewhere in the application the values, rigth?